# Registered trademark symbol - which is better HTML entity or markup?

Tags: html, html-entities

Currently, in all of our html pages, we use the &reg; entity for showing the registered trademark symbol, which up until this point I thought was the correct way to have the symbol be shown.  However, now one of my tasks is to go through all of the pages and replace it with <sup>®</sup>.

I wanted to tell my boss that it's wrong to do it this way, but I actually couldn't find any articles that discuss this and which approach is the correct approach.  Until this point, I just assumed using the html entity approach was the right way but now I'm not so sure. Is there a reason why my boss would want to use the  tags? What would be the advantage, if any? Maybe browser compatibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a properly encoded site, there is no reason to use HTML entities any more. Just enter the actual character in the right encoding.

However, it seems like what your boss *really* wants is to *change the way the character looks*. Turning the entity into the actual character is probably only a side-effect, if he's aware of it at all.

This is what it looks like without the `<sup>`: ®

This is what it looks like with the `<sup>`: <sup>®</sup>

Comment: Late to the party, but I wouldn't say there's *no* reason. If you need something like `<` or `>` as plain-text, then you need to use an entity, and while HTML validation has sort of fallen out of popularity, if you want valid HTML, you *must* encode `&` as `&amp;`. Also, since most people don't have a keyboard with all the characters present, it's usually just easier to type `&reg;` than to go to Character Map or something to find it, copy it and paste it. The point should be that if you're using unicode, you can drop the characters as-is. You only *need* entities when you're in ASCII.